AWS Cognito API Delay Across Regions?
I am creating a Cognito Pre Sign-up lambda trigger using Python 3.11.  I have noticed there's a delay between when the AdminCreateUser response is returned and when the user is actually created.  I know this is the case since when I use call the sleep() function between the API calls, it gives enough time for the user to actually be created.  My hunch is that it is related to regions since I am currently in Europe (eu-west-2 AZ) and our Cognito User Pool is in North America(us-east-1 AZ).  This is problematic as once a user has been created, I call the listUsers API to retrieve the user and link the account to their existing accounts (idPs etc.).  What is the fix to this issue?
Code snippet:
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    user_pool_id = event['userPoolId']

    generated_username = generate_username()
    generated_password = generate_password()

    response = client.admin_create_user(
        UserPoolId=user_pool_id,
        Username=generated_username,
        UserAttributes=[
            {
                'Name': 'email',
                'Value': event['request']['userAttributes']['email']
            },
            {
                'Name': 'email_verified',
                'Value': 'true'
            },
            {
                'Name': 'name',
                'Value': event['request']['userAttributes']['name']
            },
        ],
        TemporaryPassword=generated_password,
        ForceAliasCreation=True,
        MessageAction='SUPPRESS',
        DesiredDeliveryMediums=['EMAIL']
    )

    print(f"admin_create_user:\n{response}")

    response = client.list_users(
        UserPoolId=user_pool_id,
        Filter='email = \"{}\"'.format(event['request']['userAttributes']['email'])
    )

    print(f"list_users:\n{response}")

    response = client.admin_set_user_password(
        UserPoolId=user_pool_id,
        Username=generated_username,
        Password=generated_password,
        Permanent=True
    )

    print(f"admin_set_user_password:\n{response}")

    sleep(5)  # WITHOUT SLEEP THE NEW USER IS NOT RETURNED

    response = client.list_users(
        UserPoolId=user_pool_id,
        Filter='email = \"{}\"'.format(event['request']['userAttributes']['email'])
    )

    print(f"list_users:\n{response}")

    if event['userName'].startswith('google_'):
        provider_name = 'Google'
    elif event['userName'].startswith('signinwithapple_'):
        provider_name = 'SignInWithApple'
    else:
        raise Exception("Provided provider is not supported")

    provider_user_id = event['userName'].split('_')[1]  # Provider-specific user ID

    for user in response['Users']:
        client.admin_link_provider_for_user(
            UserPoolId=event['userPoolId'],
            DestinationUser={  # Existing user
                'ProviderName': 'Cognito',
                'ProviderAttributeValue': user['Username'],
            },
            SourceUser={
                'ProviderName': provider_name,
                'ProviderAttributeName': 'Cognito_Subject',
                'ProviderAttributeValue': provider_user_id
            }
        )
    return event


"since I am currently in eu-west-2 and our Cognito User Pool is in us-east-1" Those aren't availability zones, those are regions. Availability zones are datacenters inside a single region, geographically close to each other. You are dealing with two regions on opposite sides of an ocean.

Note that all the Cognito API calls you are making are going to the same API in a single region, so the fact your code is running in a different region would not be causing this issue. I expect it's just some sort of caching thing happening inside the AWS Cognito service that is causing this delay.

@MarkB my apologies, I meant to say regions.  So is there likely no way around this since it is on their side?  I suppose I could implement some sort of retry mechanism  after I have called AdminCreateUser?
